# How to animate mapped elements one at a time in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I mapped an object array to create a tag element with the details being mapped onto the element. And then I created an animation so on render, the tags zoom in to full scale. However, I was wanting to take it to the next step and wanted to animate each tag individually, **so that each tag is animated in order one after the other**. To me, this seems like a common use of animations, so how could I do it from my example? Is there any common way to do this that I am missing?

```
import {LeftIconsRightText} from '@atoms/LeftIconsRightText';
import {LeftTextRightCircle} from '@atoms/LeftTextRightCircle';
import {Text, TextTypes} from '@atoms/Text';
import VectorIcon, {vectorIconTypes} from '@atoms/VectorIcon';
import styled from '@styled-components';
import * as React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Animated, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export interface ICustomerFeedbackCard {
  title: string;
  titleIconName: string[];
  tagInfo?: {feedback: string; rating: number}[];
}

export const CustomerFeedbackCard: React.FC<ICustomerFeedbackCard> = ({
  title,
  titleIconName,
  tagInfo,
  ...props
}) => {
  const FAST_ZOOM = 800;
  const START_ZOOM_SCALE = 0.25;
  const FINAL_ZOOM_SCALE = 1;
  const zoomAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(START_ZOOM_SCALE)).current;

  /**
   * Creates an animation with a
   * set duration and scales the
   * size by a set factor to create
   * a small zoom effect
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    const zoomIn = () => {
      Animated.timing(zoomAnim, {
        toValue: FINAL_ZOOM_SCALE,
        duration: FAST_ZOOM,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };
    zoomIn();
  }, [zoomAnim]);

  /**
   * Sorts all tags from highest
   * to lowest rating numbers
   * @returns void
   */

  const sortTags = () => {
    tagInfo?.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
  };

  /**
   * Displays the all the created tags with
   * the feedback text and rating number
   * @returns JSX.Element
   */
  const displayTags = () =>
    tagInfo?.map((tag) => (
      <TagContainer
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{scale: zoomAnim}],
          },
        ]}>
        <LeftTextRightCircle feedback={tag.feedback} rating={tag.rating} />
      </TagContainer>
    ));

  return (
    <CardContainer {...props}>
      <HeaderContainer>
        <LeftIconsRightText icons={titleIconName} textDescription={title} />
        <Icon name="chevron-right" type={vectorIconTypes.SMALL} />
      </HeaderContainer>
      <ScrollOutline>
        <ScrollContainer>
          {sortTags()}
          {displayTags()}
        </ScrollContainer>
      </ScrollOutline>
      <FooterContainer>
        <TextFooter>Most recent customer compliments</TextFooter>
      </FooterContainer>
    </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

And here is the object array for reference:

```
export const FEEDBACKS = [
  {feedback: 'Good Service', rating: 5},
  {feedback: 'Friendly', rating: 2},
  {feedback: 'Very Polite', rating: 2},
  {feedback: 'Above & Beyond', rating: 1},
  {feedback: 'Followed Instructions', rating: 1},
  {feedback: 'Speedy Service', rating: 3},
  {feedback: 'Clean', rating: 4},
  {feedback: 'Accommodating', rating: 0},
  {feedback: 'Enjoyable Experience', rating: 10},
  {feedback: 'Great', rating: 8},
];
```

**Edit: I solved it by replacing React-Native-Animated and using an Animated View and instead using Animatable and using an Animatable which has built in delay. Final solution:**

```
const displayTags = () =>
    tagInfo?.map((tag, index) => (
      <TagContainer animation="zoomIn" duration={1000} delay={index * 1000}>
        <LeftTextRightCircle feedback={tag.feedback} rating={tag.rating} />
      </TagContainer>
    ));
```

[Here is a gif of the animation](https://giphy.com/gifs/6CynNbNxk6UxuTmrd6)

Comment: try  something like recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. A clean way you could approach this problem is to develop a wrapper component, `DelayedZoom` that will render its child component with a delayed zoom. This component would take a `delay` prop that you can control to add a delay for when the component should begin animation.

```
function DelayedZoom({delay, speed, endScale, startScale, children}) {
  const zoomAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(startScale)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    const zoomIn = () => {
      Animated.timing(zoomAnim, {
        delay: delay,
        toValue: endScale,
        duration: speed,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };
    zoomIn();
  }, [zoomAnim]);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        {
          transform: [{scale: zoomAnim}],
        },
      ]}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

After this, you can use this component as follows:

```
function OtherScreen() {
  const tags = FEEDBACKS;
  const FAST_ZOOM = 800;
  const START_ZOOM_SCALE = 0.25;
  const FINAL_ZOOM_SCALE = 1;

  function renderTags() {
    return tags.map((tag, idx) => {
      const delay = idx * 10; // play around with this. Main thing is that you get a sense for when something should start to animate based on its index, idx.

      return (
        <DelayedZoom
          delay={delay}
          endScale={FINAL_ZOOM_SCALE}
          startScale={START_ZOOM_SCALE}
          speed={FAST_ZOOM}>
          {/** whatever you want to render with a delayed zoom would go here. In your case it may be TagContainer */}
          <TagContainer>
            <LeftTextRightCircle feedback={tag.feedback} rating={tag.rating} />
          </TagContainer>
        </DelayedZoom>
      );
    });
  }

  return <View>{renderTags()}</View>;
}
```

I hope this helps to point you in the right direction!

Also some helpful resources:

- Animation delays: https://animationbook.codedaily.io/animated-delay/

#### Demo

[image]

Comment: I really like your solution, however is there a way to do this easier by incorporating stagger() and an array of animated values for every tag? This is a way I want to try to approach the problem in as I feel as if it would be more in line instead of creating an entire component.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution too since it is more reusable and relatively less obtrusive. You can definitely do what you are asking but it seems like a less react-y approach to the problem and would require a bit of book-keeping. Check out this resource for some guidance on `Animated.stagger`: https://animationbook.codedaily.io/animated-stagger/. Happy to update my answer if you need further assistance!

Comment: Is there a way to use the logic of using the index to apply the effect to each element individually?

Comment: Also, I just got the change to try it and it still has the same effect of the animation triggering at the same time.

Comment: Please try to change the multiplier 10 in `renderTags` to a bigger number, like 1000 to see if it works.

Comment: Yes I did try this, and it still had the same result.

Comment: That is strange. I will set this up locally to test and debug and then get back to you in case I find something new.

Comment: Hello @IbrahimNoorMohammed. I just tested and it worked fine on my end. An edit I made was to remove the `style` prop on `TagContainer` it is no longer necessary. Kindly check to see if that fixes your issue!

Comment: Here's an expo snack for you to check out exactly what I did: https://snack.expo.dev/@rexessilfie/delayedzoomsample. Let me know if you can figure it out.

Comment: The thing is I want to avoid creating an entire component in here and making default props as I am taking the functional component approach and this should be it's own component. I was thinking of simply adding a delay to the map, or some simpler solution like that. Would that be possible?

Comment: I would've suggested using `DelayedZoom` component under the hood of `TagContainer` to get to a solution similar to what you arrived at. Glad you could find a way that works best for you.

Comment: First of all, i want to thank you for giving this solution. This is my first time using this lib. I got error when i use the snippet. 
```config.easing is not a function```
tried to pass ```easing : Easing.ease()```
and now i got error ```Bezier node argument should be of type AnimatedNode but got undefined```. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of work to implement this, I didn't have your components to try it out so I have created a basic implementation, I hope this will help

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated } from "react-native";

const OBJ = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

const Item = ({ data, addValue }) => {
  const zoomAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    const zoomIn = () => {
      Animated.timing(zoomAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start(() => {
        addValue();
      });
    };
    zoomIn();
  }, [zoomAnim]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View
        ref={zoomAnim}
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{ scale: zoomAnim }]
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{data}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([OBJ[0]]);
  const addValue = () => {
    const currentId = state[state.length - 1].id;
    if (OBJ[currentId]) {
      const temp = [...state];
      temp.push(OBJ[currentId]);
      setState(temp);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      {state.map((item) => {
        return <Item data={item.id} key={item.id} addValue={addValue} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
});

export default App;
```

Basically, I am adding an element to the state at the end of the previous animation, one thing to note is that the key is very important, and don't use the index as a key. instead of Ids you might want to add any other value that is sorted or maybe link an item by passing the id of the previous item.

**ADDING A SOLUTION USING REANIMATED AND MOTI**

There is this library which you can use moti(https://moti.fyi/) it will work with reanimated, so you need to add reanimated too. Before using Reanimated you must consider that your normal chrome dev tools for that particular application will stop working with reanimated 2.0 and above you can use flipper though.

coming to the solution.

```
import { View as MotiView } from 'moti';

...
 const displayTags = () =>
    tagInfo?.map((tag, index) => (
      <MotiView
           key = {tag.id}
           from={{ translateY: 20, opacity: 0 }}
           animate={{ translateY: 0, opacity: 1 }}
           transition={{ type: 'timing' }}
           duration={500}
           delay={index * 150}>
      <TagContainer
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{scale: zoomAnim}],
          },
       ]}>
        <LeftTextRightCircle feedback={tag.feedback} rating={tag.rating} />
     </TagContainer>
     </MotiView>
  ));
...
```

That's it, make sure to use a proper key, don't use index as key.
**Side Note:** If you are doubtful that sould you use reanimated or not, just go through https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/ this page. Using Moti you can have really cool animation easily also if you reanimated version 2.3.0-alpha.1 then you need not to use Moti but as it is alpha version so it is not advisable to use in production you can wait for its stable release too.

Comment: If I just add id to the object array, will that be a workaround to use as a key as well? Thank you for your help, I have been trying to discuss this issue for three days now, but I will try this asap.

Comment: yeah, if you can do that. just dont change the key dynamically. If you change the key then it will re render the whole component and it will reanimate that will not be the behavior that you want. If you are open to add a library and use Reanimated library too let me know I have much more reliable solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, I am open to using reanimated, what is the more reliable solution?

Comment: added the current answer you can check

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use moti only reanimated

Comment: @IbrahimNoorMohammed you can use 2.3.0-alpha.1 version of reanimated, you will not need moti in that case.